# HTACCESS RewriteCond on multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a HTACCESS rewrite rule which ignores the .co.uk index.

So for example, if I goto www.mydomain.co.uk/mypage it redirects to www.mydomain.com/mypage

However if I goto www.mydomain.co.uk is stays on www.mydomain.co.uk, as soon as they hit an inner page it redirects to the .com address.

If the user comes in on www.mydomain.com they stay on the .com domain

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in the document root of your **www.mydomain.co.uk** domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.(html?|php))?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you don't want a permanent redirect, remove the `=301` part from the rule's flag.